# using regular expressions (regex) to make replace multiple patterns at the same time in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a vector of strings and I want to remove -es from all strings (words) ending in either -ses or -ces at the same time. The reason I want to do it at the same time and not consequitively is that sometimes it happens that after removing one ending, the other ending appears while I don't want to apply this pattern to a single word twice.
I have no idea how to use two patterns at the same time, but this is the best I could:

```
text <- gsub("[sc]+s$", "[sc]", text)
```

I know the *replacement* is not correct, but I wonder how can I show that I want to replace it with the letter I just detected (*c* or *s* in this case). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove `es` at the end of *words*, that is preceded with `s` or `c`, you may use

```
gsub("([sc])es\\b", "\\1", text)
gsub("(?<=[sc])es\\b", "", text, perl=TRUE)
```

To remove them at the end of *strings*, you can go on using your `$` anchor:

```
gsub("([sc])es$", "\\1", text)
gsub("(?<=[sc])es$", "", text, perl=TRUE)
```

The first `gsub` TRE pattern is `([sc])es\b`: a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) #1 that matches either `s` or `c`, and then `es` is matched, and then `\b` makes sure the next char is not a letter, digit or `_`. The `\1` in the replacement is the backreference to the value stored in the capturing group #1 memory buffer.

In the second example with the PCRE regex (due to `perl=TRUE`), `(?<=[sc])` [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is used instead of the `([sc])` capturing group. Lookbehinds are not consuming text, the text they match does not land in the match value, and thus, there is no need to restore it anyhow. The replacement is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Strings ending with "ces" and "ses" follow the same pattern, i.e. "*es$"

If I understand it correctly than you don't need two patterns.

Example:
`x = c("ces", "ses", "mes)`

`gsub( pattern = "*([cs])es$", replacement = "\\1", x)`

[1] "c"   "s"   "mes"

Hope it helps.

M

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to exclude any other possibilities like -mes for example.